# PhpStorm не открывает файлы через xdebug.file_link_format

Tags: php, phpstorm

PhpStorm не открывает файлы через xdebug.file_link_format
Уже перепробовал разные форматы, и все равно не открывает. 
Открываю ссылку в новой вкладке и ничего не происходит. Путь пишется правильно, но ничего не происходит.

```
xdebug.file_link_format = "phpstorm://open?file=%f&line=%l"
```

Comment: Странно что раньше работало. Может не прописано в PATH? Или убрали поддержку?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я создал свой протокол и программу для открытия файлов в phpstorm.

myproto.reg:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\myproto]
@="phpstorm"
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\myproto\shell]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\myproto\shell\open]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\myproto\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe\" \"C:\\Users\\Alexander\\Desktop\\web\\ahk\\phpstorm.js\" \"%1\""
```

phpstorm.js:

```
const child_process = require('child_process');
const fs = require('fs')

let path = process.argv[2]
path = path.replace('myproto://','')
path = decodeURIComponent(path)
path = path.replace(/\/$/,'')

ls = child_process.exec('"C:\\Program Files\\JetBrains\\PhpStorm 2019.1.1\\bin\\phpstorm64.exe" ' + path + '')
```

php.ini:

```
xdebug.file_link_format = "myproto://%f:%l"
```